# Check if range of values contains list of value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of 21 numbers, where they are spilt into three groups.

```
Numbers    Result
1.  22      25
2.  28
3.  25
4.  24
5.  23
6.  27
7.  26
-----------
8.  28      25
9.  24
10. 27
11. 26
12. 23
13. 22
14. 25
-----------
15. 12      9
16. 9
17. 8
18. 11
19. 10
20. 6
21. 7
```

I am currently trying to check if these 3 groups of numbers contains the following either one of the numbers: 1,9,17,25. I store the 4 numbers in column X of the same worksheet. There will not be a situation where both numbers appear in the same group. How do go about doing the check where the results is shown as above? The solution needs to be in VBA. I need to do the check 3 times as I have 3 different groups. These 3 groups of numbers are listed in one column.

Comment: Any specific problem you faced while trying?

Comment: nope didn't face any problem or error. I just don't know how to go about doing this

Comment: Where do you store the numbers 1,9,17, and 25?

Comment: @GowthamShiva I store it in the same worksheet in column X

Comment: @RachelChia What if 2 numbers are present in a group?

Comment: @GowthamShiva there will not be such a situation where 2 numbers are present in a group.

Answer (score 0):

**This formula assumed that the question needed a worksheet formula function. (See comments)**

Assuming your list of number is starting from B2, and your lookup values are in G1:G4:

You can use the following array formula (entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX(B2:B8,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH($G$1:$G$4,B2:B8,0),0)))
```

Assumiing you have "--------" after each group, you can copy the following array formula in the cell below the above formula. This is enable you to do a quick drag down.

```
=IF(B9="--------",INDEX(B10:B16,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH($G$1:$G$4,B10:B16,0),0))),"")
```

Comment: are you able to use the formula more flexible for a few times in a loop? Like the one above , i need to do it 3 times. You can assume the column no worries.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. Do you mean copying it for other similar data?

Comment: i have 21 numbers, each time i can use that formula on one group of numbers which contains 7 numbers. Hence, in total there are 3 groups. Meaning that I have to use the formula 3 times for the 3 groups

Comment: You just have to copy and paste it. Should work because you have 7 numbers for each group. Ensure you paste it in the same row as the first number in that particular group.

Comment: As in copy & paste on the worksheet right ? Sorry but im doing on the vba itself not the worksheet

Comment: I guess I provided the answer to a wrong question then. My answer is supposed to be entered in a worksheet. It doesn't make use of any vba. You should mention the same in your question that you want a vba solution.

Comment: @RachelChia Can't the above formula be used in vba using application.WorksheetFunction? (Just an idea)

Comment: wouldn't the formula be too long ?